# Is there any possible way to use Controller and RestController annotations in one Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, json, spring, controller

I have my application, which is running on Spring Boot. In my application, I have two controllers, @RestController and @Controller. 
Rest is for returning JSON data and Controller is for HTML pages. When I try to use these two boys in my one project, it always gives me an error code: 
**Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [index]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause** 
My HTML page is located in **resources:/templates**. 
RequestMappingClass:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/")
public class PageRestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/getUserData")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
        User user = new User();

        user.setName("Nika");
        user.setSurname("Beridze");
        user.setAge(19);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```java
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency?

Comment: no, why I need it?

Comment: Well what type of views are you using? If you're using resources/templates, you should probably be using Thymeleaf.

Comment: No one, in my HTML page is just a Hello World

Comment: Did you configure any view resolver?

Comment: In any case, adding `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` should allow it to work since your structure is exactly that of a Thymeleaf project.

Comment: I try to configure it, but It gives me the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency. This automatically registers a view resolver for HTML files in src/main/resources/templates.